# How do i Subtract only 2 cells in excel IF they are not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Cell C7 and Cell C2. I want to have the difference between C7 and C2 if neither of these cells are blank.

Simply doing = C7-C2   returns #Value when cells are blank.

I have tried SUMIF , IF and i cannot find a way after many attempts.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You won't recieve that error when cells are actually empty. So I suppose those cells hold formulas on their own, and at times they may evaluate to `""`? Also, you want the difference, but do you always want `C7-C2`? Do you always want a positive difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my comment, I suspect both cells got formulas on their own that would evaluate to `""` at times resulting in a `#VALUE` error. I guess you want to `COUNT` the cells holding numbers first then. So try:

```
=IF(COUNT(C2,C7)=2,C7-C2,"Missing value(s)")
```

Would you need the difference to be positive:

```
=IF(COUNT(C2,C7)=2,ABS(C7-C2),"Missing value(s)")
```